# Can conditions apply on filtering results using django-filters?

Tags: django, django-filter

How can I apply conditions of filtering results using django-filters 
For example I have a field say 'Bookscount' having integer values and if user opts for value > 5 then django-filter displays all those books having 'Bookscount' > 5

```
import django_filters as df
from .models import Books


class BooksListFilter(df.FilterSet):
 class Meta:
   model = Books
   fields = ['Bookscount']
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to declare the filter, or generate it with `Meta.fields`

```
class BooksListFilter(df.FilterSet):
    min_books = df.NumberFilter(field_name='Bookscount', lookup_expr='gte')

# or
class BooksListFilter(df.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Books
        fields = {'Bookscount': ['gt']}
```